How could I replace Iterrows in this piece of code to make it more efficient?
I am relatively new to Pandas and many of my programs are heavily reliant on iterrows, which I am now looking to replace to make it more efficient. How could I rewrite the following piece of code to use vectorisation:
    for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
        if float(row['a']) == key_1:
            df.iloc[index, 14] = row['key_2']
        else:
            df.iloc[index, 14] = row['key_1']


The general concept is df[df['a'] == key_1]] = df[df['a'] == key_1]['key_1]`.  This is called "smart indexing".  The inner comparison returns a list of booleans, and the assignment only takes place where the booleans are true.

IIUC, df.iloc[:, 14] = np.where(df['a'].eq(key_1), df['key_2'], df['key_1']). If not, please provide a [mre].

If you really do need to loop over rows then itertuples() is significantly faster than iterrows(). That said, both are much slower than a vectorized approach which should always be used if possible.
